# Is there a way to get the local maven repository path?

Tags: maven, cygwin

I have the problem that when using the windows maven under cygwin, the local repository path is not /home/user/.m2/repository, it is /cygdrive/c/Users/user/.m2/repository.

Is there a way, with some python library or Aether or something like that, to find out the path that the actual maven binary uses?

Comment: For which purpose do you need that?

Comment: I am using jip to download dependencies, and it fails to find locally built/installed artifacts. jip is a maven API for python. The reason for failing being that it looks for the repository at ~/.m2/repository, but my maven build put it in the Windows home, not the cygwin one. For the time being, my workaround is to add $USERPROFILE/.m2/repository as local repository, using $HOME if $USERPROFILE is not set (to keep the workaround as portable as possible, since the stuff is going to run on a Linux machine eventually)

Comment: Actually, the better workaround is to point $HOME to $USERPROFILE